# encode a groovy variable using base64

Tags: java, groovy

I have a string like this and am trying to encode this string using base64

```
{"htmlBrowserType":"Default","mimeType":"text/html","url":"https://github.comcast.com"}

String base64Config =   {"htmlBrowserType\":\"Default\",\"mimeType\":\"text/html\",\"url\":\"https://github.comcast.com"}
```

Actually it is a groovy code

```
    def encoded = base64Config.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```

While encoding using the tool am getting

```
eyJodG1sQnJvd3NlclR5cGUiOiJEZWZhdWx0IiwibWltZVR5cGUiOiJ0ZXh0L2h0bWwiLCJ1cmwiOiJodHRwczovL2dpdGh1Yi5jb21jYXN0LmNvbSJ9
```

But it is not working using java code while am decoding the string getting as the result of the above java code is not

```
{"htmlBrowserType":"Default","mimeType":"text/html","url":"https://github.comcast.com"}
```

Comment: What Java code are you using to decode the string?  What you showed us above is only half the story.  What is the output you are getting?

Comment: while i decode the output am getting 'com.uegGlue$_base64_configuration_is_generated_with_url_parameter_set_to_closure1@23c1e787'

Comment: Your Groovy code to encode looks OK, but we need to see the code you used to decode.  My guess is that this is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

Your `base64Config` is not a String, but Closure:

```
String base64Config = {"htmlBrowserType\":\"Default\",\"mimeType\":\"text/html\",\"url\":\"https://github.comcast.com"}
```

It should be:

```
String base64Config = "{\"htmlBrowserType\":\"Default\",\"mimeType\":\"text/html\",\"url\":\"https://github.comcast.com\"}"
```

Comment: I always prefer `'{"htmlBrowserType":"Default","mimeType":"text/html","url":"https://github.comcast.com"}'` so you don't need escaping

Comment: @tim_yates yes, agree